# Second transition_post_status hook fired instead of the first

Tags: php, posts, post-status

I'm using `transition_post_status` to move a post into another post type based on the `$new_status`, I had made two hooks but the second one always firing first even though the `$new_status` is '`publish`'. I has try to change the priority but didn't work either, try to combine them into one hook also not working either...

```
//Move Group Queue CPT to Group Post Type
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'groupqueue_to_groupcpt', 10, 3);
function groupqueue_to_groupcpt($new_status, $old_status, $post){
    //Move to Group Post Type
    if ('publish' === $new_status
        && 'groupq' === $post->post_type
    )
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'group'
        ), true );
}

//Move Group Queue or Group CPT to Banned Post Type
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'groupcpt_to_bannedcpt', 10, 5);
function groupcpt_to_bannedcpt($new_status, $old_status, $post){
    if ( 'banned' === $new_status
        && 'groupq' === $post->post_type xor 'group' === $post->post_type
    )
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'banned'
        ), true );
}
```

If I remove the `groupcpt_to_bannedcpt`, the first one will be running fine. Is there a solution to this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user `if..else` condition to combine both function into one hook.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'groupqueue_to_groupcpt_and_groupcpt_to_bannedcpt', 10, 3);
function groupqueue_to_groupcpt_and_groupcpt_to_bannedcpt($new_status, $old_status, $post){
    //Move to Group Post Type
    if ('publish' === $new_status  && 'groupq' === $post->post_type )
    {    
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'group'
        ), true );
    }
    else if ( 'banned' === $new_status && ('groupq' === $post->post_type || 'group' === $post->post_type))
    {
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'        => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'banned'
        ), true );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it seems I still need to look back to basic sometimes... it fixed by a simple statement.